# Intel Iris Graphics card not visible in Virtual box win-7

Tags: virtualbox, drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have 13" inch macbook retina which comes with an Intel Iris 1538 MB graphics card. I have installed windows-7 in my VirtualBox.

Now, when I go to check the details about graphics card in the windows-7 of virtualbox, it does not show my Intel Iris graphics card.

I even tried to install the `OpenCL` graphics card driver but it got failed with a message that the system does not meet the requirements.

[image]

Comment: Also, your graphics card doesn’t have 1538 MB of memory. It’s [shared memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_graphics_memory).

Comment: @DanielB: I just wrote its name as displayed in the info. I never said that it has 1538 MB memory.

Answer (score 5):

A virtual machine does not have access to physical device in your computer &  hence you cannot install native drivers in the guest machine.

All the devices are emulated by the virtual machine (Hypervisor if we are to say it more accurately)

You should start with adding virtual guest additions & refer to learn [how to emulate 2D/3D acceleration in Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#guestadd-video)

Comment: I have enabled the 3D Acceleration and I am able to see that it is enable in the DirectX Diagonstic tool. But I am still not able to install the `intel Iris graphics driver` in Virtualbox win-7.

Comment: You won't be able to as the device is not present there physically. That's what i meant when I said **you cannot install native drivers in the guest machine**

Comment: So, what could be the solution to install Intel OpenCL for graphics card based programming ?

Comment: There is a lot of discussion around this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298453/cuda-opencl-within-a-virtual-machine-hypervisor you may want to see if it helps